# Django remove trailing slashes - urls or redirect

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm trying to remove the trailing slashes in my `urls` or make redirection happen if a slash is added at the end. I tried to do it on resources from the Internet but it does not work for me. I guess I'm doing something wrong.

**urls.py - app**

```
app_name = 'shop'
urlpatterns = [
    # product
    path('', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    path('show/<slug:slug>', views.product_show, name='product_show'),
    path('<slug:category>', views.product_list, name='lst_by_ctgry'),
    path('<slug:category>/<slug:subcategory>', views.product_list, name='lst_by_subctgry'),
    path('<slug:category>/<slug:subcategory>/<slug:kind>', views.product_list, name='lst_by_knds'),
    # info - these urls doesn't work without slashes. works only with slashes
    path('pad', views.pad, name='pad'),
    path('guarantee', views.guarantee, name='guarantee'),
    path('contacts', views.contacts, name='contacts'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
    path('privacy', views.privacy, name='privacy')
]
```

**urls.py - project**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('orders.urls')),
    path('', include('cart.urls')),
    path('', include('shop.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**settings.py**

```
APPEND_SLASH = False
REMOVE_SLASH = True
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

Сan you give an example please how can i remove trailing slashes in all urls or get redirect

Comment: It’s convention to have a trailing slash for URLs. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @IainShelvington, I want to make it so that at the end of the URL there is no slash, and if it is added, then it will be redirected to the address without a dash

Answer (score 10):

Though it's recommended to use the trailing slash. But if you don't want to have that, you can change it in `settings.py` file of your project.

**settings.py**

```py
APPEND_SLASH = False
```

The default value is `True`.

See in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash).

Comment: Can you share the exact resource which recommends keeping the trailing slash as-is?

Comment: This is a partial answer. It won't redirect if trailing slash *is* found. When `APPEND_SLASH=True`, Django will redirect and add a slash. When `APPEND_SLASH=False`, Django will **not** redirect and remove a slash.

Answer (score 10):

The highest voted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57027332/5556320) at the time of my writing, didn't really answer the question being posed.

**Default Behavior**

- By default (APPEND_SLASH = True), if Django cannot find a requested URL (say https://smartavery.com/about) then it looks for the same URL with an appended slash (i.e. https://smartavery.com/about/), and if found redirects to it (*301*)
- Changing this default behavior (APPEND_SLASH = False) will simply lead Django to send a "404 error" instead of a "301 redirect"

**OP's Question**:
The OP is asking the opposite question. "How can I remove trailing slashes or get a redirect?". My (*unhelpful*) answer would be to go through your code base and remove trailing slashes from URL definitions. Django will not "fix" it for you.

**Django convention - URLs with trailing slash**
The recommendation to always use a trailing slash is a Django convention (*which I don't exactly love*). As a practical matter within Django:

- If you define all of your URLs with a trailing slash, and some client comes looking for a URL without a slash, they'll be okay. Because Django will automatically redirect them to the URL with a slash
- If your URLs do not have a trailing slash, and some client comes looking for a URL with a slash, they're out of luck. Django will give them a "404 not found"