# Remove trailing slashes in Django URLs

Tags: python, django, string, middleware

Is there any way of stripping all trailing URLs in Django and redirecting them to the non slashed URL.

i.e. If I go to /home/ I want to be redirected to /home.
Currently I get a 404 as the page "does not exist".

There was one piece of middleware I found which is outdated. Called Django-unslashed.

Would this be a case of adding something to the urlconf, or writing custom middleware?

EDIT:
I have found one solution from https://gist.github.com/gregplaysguitar/1440567

EDIT EDIT:
The Django version I am currently using is 2.2, and will soon be upgraded to 3.0

Comment: How would that apply for development environments?

Comment: I guess one would read this kind of articles: https://realpython.com/django-redirects/

Comment: The [common middleware](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3d4ffd1ff0eb9343ee41de77caf6ae427b6e873c/django/middleware/common.py#L34) lets you do the opposite, and redirect (say) `/home` to `/home/`. So a middleware is the correct approach. The fork [`tocka-django-unslashed`](https://pypi.org/project/tocka-django-unslashed/) looks like it might work on recent versions of Django, because it uses `MiddlewareMixin`.

Comment: @Alasdair The fork you suggested fails to work as it requires an import from urlresolvers.

Comment: There's a PR to fix that https://github.com/frnhr/django-unslashed/pull/1/files, but it's been open since 2017 so I wouldn't expect it to be merged/released soon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django remove trailing slashes - urls or redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57027259/django-remove-trailing-slashes-urls-or-redirect)

Comment: No. That's for removing backslashes by default. Which is something that Django does. What I want to do is strip the backslash and redirect to the non backslash URL.